# The double ⟨l⟩ in Spanish

Tags: etymology, cross-linguistic, orthography, spanish

In Spanish, some words start with the double consonant graphemes ⟨`ll`⟩ - that have indeed the value of `/ʎ/`.

Is there any language that have a similar pattern (starting with double consonants)? What is the origin of this "phenomena"?

(I know, at least, that Arabic does not have such pattern).

Comment: The Castilian Spanish phoneme /ʎ/ is [represented as LL in Spanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ll#Spanish). In many other dialects of Spanish (notably Mexican Spanish), this phoneme has merged with /y/, and there is only one phoneme with two spellings. In much the same way, Castilian Spanish has a /θ/ phoneme spelled with C (before I or E), and Z elsewhere. In Mexican Spanish, /θ/ has merged with /s/ and S, Z, and C (before I or E) can all be pronounced the same way: /s/.

Comment: Just in case it wasn't clear from jlawler's comment, the "double consonant" here is just a spelling convention: it really stands for a single sound. If you're asking whether there are other languages whose writing systems represent single phonemes with orthographic geminates, and where these can be initial, then yes. Welsh is an example: *ff* stands for [f], *ll* stands for voiceless [l], and both can be word-initial.

Comment: @TKR The Welsh ⟨ll⟩ is a voiceless lateral fricative (/ɬ/). Examples of the two occurring in the initial position, if jihed is interested, are _ffaith_ 'fact' and _llaeth_ 'milk'. Other letters like ⟨d⟩ (in _y ddafad_). However, in Welsh, these are letter in their own rights and not the same letter repeated twice.

Comment: English having such a convoluted orthography, it seems to have examples of almost everything: the grapheme <w> derives historically from an orthographic geminate; and of course there is the English surname 'Ffoulkes' (I wont' mention borrowings such as <llama>!).

Comment: @jlawler: You mean the Castilian Spanish in Castile or the Castillian of Argentina and Uruguay? They're very different and the double usage of the word often leads to confusion and misunderstandings.

Comment: @DangerFourpence: In Spanish `ll` was traditionally regarded as a letter in its own right until a reform a few years ago to make it easier to sort alphabetically on computers. Ironically this came at just the time when sorting in manners exotic compared to English was becoming quite trivial on computers.

Comment: I meant the native Spanish of the European invaders of the Americas. Wherever they wound up.

Comment: @jlawler: Oh so you mean the entire set of varieties that "Spanish" also covers? Yes that's the third meaning of "Castilian" - very ambiguous term... Including Mexico?? You seemed to be contrasting Castilian and Mexican Spanish so now I *am* confused.

Comment: I am contrasting a phonological phenomenon in 16th-Century Spanish with one in modern Mexican Spanish, and implying that both phenomena also occur and occurred in other dialects of Spanish.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no Spanish variety in Latin America that consistently contrasts `ll` and `y` or `c`, `s`, and `z`. If they pronounce `ll` something like `/ʎ/` they use that pronunciation also for `y`. But yes I believe most of the variety that exists around Latin America also exists in varieties around Spain.

Comment: If Sp. trilled r were always written "rr", as it is when intervocalic, then r would also display "a similar pattern (starting with double consonants)."

Comment: Right. There's also an initial *RR* in Albanian, but I have no idea what it represents in terms of phonology.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is based on a very common lack of understanding about the difference between ***orthography*** and ***phonology***.

Language is ancient, prehistoric. The first writing systems we know of are only about three thousand year old innovations. Writing and orthography are basically an artificial technology invented by people as an enhancement to the naturally occurring language we have always had.

But oddly enough there is one language I know of that answers this question in every way.

Albanian has a `"ll"` digraph which is counted as a separate letter and represents a different sound to the Albanian letter `"l"` (though not the same sound the Spanish `"ll"` represents).

And the Albanian `"ll"` can also occur at the beginning of words. Here are the ones currently in the English Wiktionary [[1]](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Albanian_nouns&pagefrom=ll#mw-pages), [[2]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Albanian/ll):

- llaf, llapë, llastoj, llasë, llautë, llënjëz, llërë, lloj, lloj brejtësi, lloji, llom, llucë, lluke, llullaq, llum, llup, llups, llurbë

Comment: Albanian also has a letter _rr_, which can be initial.

Comment: Yes and while Spanish has a digraph `rr` which represents a distinct sound from `r`, `rr` was never counted as a single letter as `ch` and `ll` were until recently. A lot of people think it was though.

Comment: Spanish also has `ñ` which was previously written `nn` until the second n slipped above the first.  It is uncommon as an initial letter, but a wildebeest is *ñu* in Spanish (*gnu* in English with the same pronunciation until a 1960s song changed fashions)

Comment: As an Albanian native speaker, Albanian ll is a letter in and of itself. Ll is similar to L in language spoken by an American, while l is L in langue spoken by a Frenchman. Rr is similar to Italian terra.

Comment: @Henry, so we really should sing "I'm a nyu, I'm the nyicest nyanimal in the zyu!"

Comment: "three thousand years" > "about five and a half thousand years".

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** In most Latin American Spanish dialects (and most of Southern Spain) *ll* has merged with consonantal *y*, i.e. `/j ~ ʝ/`, not `/ʎ/`.
>
> In many dialects of Argentina and Uruguay, "ll" / "y" represents `/ʒ/` or `/ʃ/`.<sup>2</sup>

There are a few other Iberian romance languages that also use `ll` to represent `/ʎ/`, and within these there are words which are `ll-` initial (Catalan in particular has a large amount of words that begin as such):

- **Aragonese** - *agulla*
- **Asturian / Leonese** - *llingua*
- **Galician** - *illado*
- **Catalan** - *llum*

The non-romance Iberian language Basque also uses `ll` to represent this sound:

- **Basque** - *bonbilla*

And in some dialects of French `ll` is also still pronounced as such (though in most it has merged with `/j/`).<sup>3</sup>

In Occitan, Mirandese, Portuguese (which inherited this orthography from Occitan)<sup>4</sup> and Breton, this sound is represented by `lh`.

- **Occitan** - *miralhar*
- **Portuguese** - *ralho*
- **Mirandese** - *lhéngua*
- **Breton** - *familh*

In Franco-Provençal this sound is represented by `ly`, and in Aromanian by `lj`:

- **Franco-Provençal** - *balyi*
- **Aromanian** - *ljepuri*

In Italian this sound is represented by `gli` before *a, e, o, u* and `gl` before *i*:

- **Italian** - *figlio*, *eglino*

In addition, a number of native American languages which have had historic contact with Spanish colonies and have this sound in their language transcribe it with `ll`:

- **Aymara** - *ll'aki'*
- **Quechua** - *qallu*

---

**Sources:**

1. <sup>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatal_lateral_approximant</sup>
2. <sup>[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeísmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye%C3%ADsmo)</sup>
3. > [image]
   >
   > <sup>• [*Le Bon usage*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SX0wDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=l+mouill%C3%A9), André Goosse, Maurice Grevisse (§33, b, H):</sup>
4. > <sup>The Occitan classical orthography and the Catalan orthography are quite similar: They show the very close ties of both languages. The digraphs *lh* and *nh*, used in the classical orthography, were adopted by the orthography of Portuguese, presumably by [Gerald of Braga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_of_Braga), a monk from [Moissac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moissac), who became bishop of Braga in Portugal in 1047, playing a major role in modernizing written Portuguese using classical Occitan norms.<sup>[55]</sup></sup>
   >
   > <sup>• [55: *Petit précis – Chronologie occitane – Histoire & civilisation*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/2906/2711), Jean-Pierre Juge (2001) (p.25)</sup>

---

**Extra:**

<sup>A list of Catalan `ll-` initial words (not exhaustive):</sup>

<sup>llacer, llach, lladre, lladó, lladós, llama, llamas, llamp, llana, llanas, llanda, llanes, llano, llanos, llanxa, llança, llao, llapis, llar, llard, llarg, llast, llatí, llauna, llaurí, llautó, llavar, llavi, llavis, llavor, llaç, llaçar, llaüt, llebre, llec, lledó, llegar, llegir, llegua, llegum, llei, lleial, lleida, lleig, lleir, lleis, lleixa, llena, llenas, llenya, lleona, lleons, llepar, llera, llers, llesca, llest, llet, lletra, lletós, lleu, lleure, lleva, llevar, llevat, lleó, lli, llibre, lliga, lligam, lligar, lligat, llim, llima, llimac, llimar, llimó, llimós, llinas, llinda, lliri, llis, llisa, llista, llistó, llit, llitja, lliura, lliure, lliçà, lliçó, lloar, lloba, llobet, llobí, lloc, llocs, llodio, llogar, llogat, llom, llonch, llong, llonza, llop, llopis, llora, llorac, llorca, lloren, llorer, lloret, lloro, llort, llosa, llosc, llossa, llot, llotja, llotós, llovet, lloyd, llubí, llucar, lluch, llucia, lluent, lluer, lluert, lluir, lluita, [Llull](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Llull), llum, llums, llumí, lluna, lluny, llunyà, lluor, llur, llurba, llusa, lluç, lluçà, lluís, llépol, llíber, llíria, llívia, llúpol</sup>

---

**Note:**

<sup>In Catalan and Italian, `/ʎ/` is distinguished from a geminated `/l/`, by different orthographies (e.g. **cat:** *cel·la*, **it:** *cella*):</sup>

```
+----------+-------+-------+
| Language |  /ʎ/  | /l.l/ |
+----------+-------+-------+
| Catalan  | ll    | l·l   |
| Italian  | gl(i) | ll    |
+----------+-------+-------+
```